# Avoid key clash on SQL Merge Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two columns, Prime_GuestID and Dup_GuestID to indicate the links between an GuestID's and the ID(s) it is replacing (duplicate records)

Now I want to go through a number of other relationship tables of the format  and update any occurrences of a Dup_GuestID to it's Prime_GuestID.

However if the Prime_GuestID already has an entry for a given ThingID then instead I need to delete that row from the relationship table.

Currently I'm using the following script, though while it works for most cases it fails if two Dup_GuestID's update to the same Prime_GuestID for a given ThingID. It seems like the merge statement queues up all the changes before making them, therefore my clash check won't detect them.

```
MERGE Thing_Relation AS t
USING Guest_Relation AS g
    ON t.GuestID = g.Dup_GuestID
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (  -- Clash Check here
                        select * 
                        from Thing_Relation AS t2 
                        where t2.ThingID = t.ThingID 
                        and t2.GuestID = g.Prime_GuestID
                        ) 
 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED 
 THEN UPDATE SET t.GuestID = g.Prime_GuestID
```

Is there a better way to be doing the check at 'When matched and exists' to check for clashes that would result from this merge? Or is there a better way to do this whole thing?

EDIT: Here is some sample data for the table

```
Thing_Relation          Guest_Relation
ThingID | GuestID       Prime_GuestID | Dup_GuestID
------------------      ---------------------------
1       | 101                     101 | 102
1       | 102                     107 | 104
2       | 103                     107 | 105
3       | 104
3       | 105

Thing_Relation after merge
ThingID | GuestID       
------------------      
1       | 101              
2       | 103
3       | 107
```

The 1|102 gets changed to 1|101 which already exists so row is deleted.
2|103 isn't affected
3|104 is changed to 3|107, and since 3|105 also changes to 3|107 but the previous update hasn't happened yet it isn't picked up by the `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: i am not sure about your main syntax,As you said merge will fail if update is non deterministic.so instead of trying to solve it,if you still want to go ahead and update..you can use derived table which will have only one match

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get your comment. If a row would be updated to something that would clash in the table, then I want to delete that row.

However if the clash was generated by a previous update in the merge step then my `EXISTS` condition won't find it. Is there a better conditional I could be using to get around this problem?

Comment: Can you please share table schema with some sample data of the two tables you are talking about, so that we can understand the relationship between the two tables better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, MERGE would not run your checks on the changes made by the MERGE statement itself. It is the basic property of MERGE. Few of the options could be :

1. Create a TRIGGER on UPDATE that will keep on checking for clashes on every update and delete the duplicate rows. OR
2. simply write two different statements one for UPDATE, later one DELETE for duplicate entries.